# How to implement WebKitWebFrame(Webkit1 Class) in Webkit2

Tags: 16.04, webkit

**WebKitWebFrame** is a class in webkit1. But as webkit1 support is removed we have to use webkit2. But in webkit2 there is no class called **WebKitWebFrame.** Kindly help how to implement the same feature using webkit2. Though in webkit2 a class called WebKitFrame is present as Web Extensions. But their is a significant difference in their functions.

Kindly help!

Thanks.